# Proving that every interval in an o-minimal structure is definably connected.

Tags: logic, model-theory

By an ordered structure I mean a (first order) structure $\mathcal{M}=(M,<,\ldots)$ that is totally and densely ordered by $<$. An ordered structure $\mathcal{M}$ is *o-minimal* if every definable subset $A\subset M$ is finite union of points and intervals.

We consider the order topology in the ordered structure $\mathcal{M}$ and say that $A\subseteq M$ is *definably connected* if there are no definable open subsets $U_1$ and $U_2$ such that $U_1 \cap U_2 \cap A= \emptyset$ and both $A\cap U_1$ and $A\cap U_2$ are nonempty.

The above definitions are taken from Sergei Starchenko's online notes on o-minimality. Firstly I'd like to comment that the definition for definably connected seems to be missing $A\subseteq U_1 \cup U_2$. Secondly I would like to proof the following:

> Every interval in an o-minimal structure is definably connected.

Now in these notes an interval in an ordered structure $\mathcal{M}$ is defined as an interval with endpoints in $M\cup \{+\infty,-\infty\}$. The statement can then easily be proved. If we however considered an interval defined more generally as a set $I\subseteq M$ such that when $x,y\in I$ and $x<z<y$ then $z\in I$, is it still true?

Comment: Using o-minimality you can show that every definable interval in the second sense must have endpoints.

Comment: Of course @LevonHaykazyan but I'm addressing any interval here.

Comment: Note that the definition of definably connected (which you correctly copied from Sergei's notes) has a mistake: you have to also insist that $A \cap U_1$ and $A \cap U_2$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same proof that works for intervals in the usual sense also works for intervals in your sense. Assume $A \cap U_1 \neq A,\emptyset$. Then there are points $a_1 \in A \cap U_1, a_2 \in A \setminus U_1$. By o-minimality, $U_1$ is a finite union of open intervals, so there is a point $a^\star$ between $a_1$ and $a_2$ which is an (open) endpoint of $U_1$. By your notion of interval, $a^\star \in A$. In order to cover $a^\star$ with a definable open set, by o-minimality, we have to include an open interval containing $a^\star$. It is clear that any such interval must intersect $U_1 \cap A$.

Also, for your further edification, note that, by an easy compactness argument, intervals in your sense are just intervals with endpoints in an elementary extension (or, rather, the intersection of such an interval with the original model).

Comment: Could you further justify your last claim? What if $(M,<.+,.,0,1)$ is a non archimedean real closed field and the interval is the set of finite elements?

Comment: @nombre In that case, by compactness, find an elementary extension $N$ where there is an infinite element $r$ less than all the infinite elements of $M$. Then $(-r,r) \cap M$ is the interval required. I've clarified what I wrote to make it more clear that you have to intersect with your original model.

Comment: Right, thanks, I get the general idea also.

Comment: @MikeHaskel now I realise that the difficulty I found in the question came not so much from changing the definition of interval but from changing the definition of o-minimal structure by changing the definition of interval. I should have make it more clear but I didn't notice.

Comment: I think that for this proof to work, actually only one of the sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ has to be definable. The second reference to o-minimality in the proof is not necessary, the openness suffices at this point.